# Redesigning method to use Java 8 Map.computeIfAbsent() with thrown exception

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to rework some of my methods to make them more concise using Java 8, whose new features I am trying to slowly absorb.

It is a method with the purpose of adding a `value` to a `Map<Key, Set<Value>>`. There are three posibilities:

1. The key doesn't exist: it is added and a new set containing the value is associated to it.
2. The key exists: the value is added to the existing set. Note that a set will never be `null`, because I have some preconditions to deal with that.
3. The key exists and the value is already contained in the set: an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

The code implementing this behaviour is the following, and it does not use Java 8 features:

```
public void addValue(Key key, Value value) {
    // irrelevant preconditions...

    Set<Value> valuesForKey = myMap.get(key);
    if (valuesForKey != null && valuesForKey.contains(value))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Association exists already");

    if (valuesForKey == null)
        myMap.put(key, new HashSet<Value>(Arrays.asList(value)));
    else
        valuesForKey.add(value);
}
```

I would like to shorten this code using Java 8 methods like [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

I could sum up the last `if-else` block, but I can't get past the redundancy of the value set to which `key` maps to having already being retrieved when performing the precondition checks.

```
public void addValue(Key key, Value value) {
    // irrelevant preconditions...

    Set<Value> valuesForKey = myMap.get(key);
    if (valuesForKey != null && valuesForKey.contains(value))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Association exists already");

    myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, v -> new HashSet<Value>()).add(value);
}
```

Is there anyway I could merge all that in one instruction?

Comment: While you can certainly do it that way, you should consider using a `Multimap` (e.g. from Guava) instead. Having a `Map<K,Set<V>>` or `Map<K,List<V>>`is in 99% of the use cases a design smell.

Comment: @Landei, In my opinion it's not really "code smell" since the JDK has no multiset and one may not want to pull in a whole library just for that one use. It's the simplest solution available in those circumstances and the CHM's `compute*` and `merge` methods make juggling those things fairly straight-forward.

Comment: In my opinion the JDK collections are in a pitiful state (e.g. missing usable immutable collections), and I use libs like Guava for almost all projects. I made the experience that once you imported a lib like that, you will find more and more places where it is useful.

Comment: @Landei I was reading this "old" question and now I must ask, why do you say it's a bad design? In my project IMHO it makes absolute sense to use a `Map<K, Set<V>>`. I don't want to go into detail for brevity's sake but please say why it is a bad design :/

Comment: @dabadaba If Sets are really the "values" in your model (e.g. finding an empty Set under a key is something different than finding nothing), then you are in the 1% of cases, where you do it right. But if you just want to allow multiple values under one key, it is not longer a Map, it is a Multimap, which has different behavior (which you need to "simulate" when using a Map).

Comment: @Landei in my case it's pretty much to represent a one-to-many relationship. I don't see any other way to do it than using a `Map<Key, Set<Value>>` with Java, so why would it be a design flaw?

Comment: @dabadaba The only thing I can say is when I started to introduce Multimaps for such relations, the code became shorter, more intuitive to use and more readable. It was clearly the right choice for my problem. I don't know your project, so all I can say is: Try it out and see if it helps you in the same way. I know that pulling too many libs in a project is a bad idea, but sometimes you just need the right tool. See e.g. http://tomjefferys.blogspot.de/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the [`add(element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method will return `true` if the set didn't contain the specified element. If this call returns `false`, it means the element wasn't added because it was already present. Therefore, you can use:

```
public void addValue(Key key, Value value) {
    boolean added = myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
    if (!added) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Association exists already");
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't the real underlying exception this way. Frankly I don't know why compute can't throw an exception. There is no reason to why it can't. It doesn't run in a separate thread.

Comment: @momomo Why would `computeIfAbsent` throw an exception? Adding an element to a set that already exists doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: Perhaps before adding it you need to do some stuff, that might throw an exception

Comment: @momomo Sounds like code that shouldn't live in a `addValue` method then, but before calling it.

Comment: The computation needs to be done in a concurrently safe manner. But anyway, you can throw an exception wrapped in a runtime exception. In addvalue one could also declare an Exception and catch and after you could see if the return value is true and if there was an exception ...