# Add element to Set when Set is the value of a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, set

This is my Map

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to retrieve a `Set` from my `Map` and add an element to it.

```
Set<String> val = hmap.get(key);
val.add(newElement);    //NPE
hmap.put(key, val);
```

but I get `NullPointerException` on the `val.add` line

This is probably trivial, but I don't see it..

What am I missing?

Comment: It means that `hmap.get(key)` returns `null` ==> this key doesn't have a value in your map

Comment: So I need to initialize the key with a new Set?

Comment: If the key does not yet have a set, yes, you need to create one. And this is also the only case where you need to do the `hmap.put`. If there is already a set you don't need to put the same set back.

Comment: Yes, you need to have a mapping from `key` to its value which is a set in your case.

Comment: @NickGinanto I think you are new to java.
Because `get` method of `HashMap` will return null if you are not set any think in it. so first you need to initialize with `new` keyword.

Comment: You are getting **NPE** on line **val.add(newElement);**. That means **val** is null, says no such key is present in Map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redesigning method to use Java 8 Map.computeIfAbsent() with thrown exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277814/redesigning-method-to-use-java-8-map-computeifabsent-with-thrown-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following option:

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> val = hmap.get(key);
if (val == null) {
    val = new HashSet<>();
    val.add(newElement);
    hmap.put(key, val);
}
else {
    val.add(newElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing code which modifies an entry of a map given a key, it is a good idea to first check if a value exists for that particular key.

Example:

```
if (hmap.contains(key) == false) 
{
    // This will prevent the null reference issue
    hmap.put(key, new HashSet<String>());
}
Set<String> val = hmap.get(key);
val.add(newElement);
```

Also, as a side note:

```
hmap.put(key, val);
```

That line is not needed. "val" is a reference to the existing set within the map. Modifying it will modify the value mapped to key, so you don't need to call put. It's already there and has been updated.

Comment: This is not the most efficient way to do it as you will do the lookup of the same key twice. Better do the `get` and check for a `null` result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Map.computeIfAbsent()` that adds the value if the key is not present in the map.

Note that the method returns the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key. So you could use the returned object to add the String object in the Set object :

```
String key = "a key";
Set<String> val = hmap.computeIfAbsent(key, k-> new HashSet<>()); // create the hashset and associate it to the key if key not present
val.add("a value");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is actually happening

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
map.put("1_a", new HashSet<String>());

Set<String> set1 = map.get("1_a");
set1.add("a");

System.out.println(set1);

Set<String> set2 = map.get("1_b");  // Not present
set2.add("a");   // NPE - set2 will be null.
```

You can add a check mentioned by @Stephano, it will be always handy.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short you also can do like:

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
String key = "key";
String newElement = "ele";

if (!hmap.containsKey(key)) {
    hmap.put(key, new HashSet<>());
}
hmap.get(key).add(newElement);
```